# grep syntax for searching strings with single-quotes?

Tags: shell, grep, quoting

So, I have a .js file as below and I am trying to search with the below grep pattern. I am not sure what mistake I did but it does not give any output even though the file has that pattern. What mistake am I doing and how to correct it?

`.js` file:

```
var View = require('ampersand-view');
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
require('bootstrap-tooltip');
var extend = require('lodash/assign');
```

my requirement is to find any occurrences of: `require('query')`

grep I am using: `grep 'require('jquery')' index.js`

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes cannot be embedded in single-quoted strings.  Try:

```
$ grep "require('jquery')" index.js
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Alternatively, you can end the single-quoted string, add an escaped single-quote, and then restart the single-quoted string:

```
$ grep 'require('\''jquery'\'')' index.js
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

#### Discussion

To understand better what is happening, you can use echo statements to see how the shell processes strings:

```
$ echo 'require('jquery')'
require(jquery)
```

In the above example, there are two single-quoted strings: `require(` and `)`.  As far as the shell is concerned, the string `jquery` is unquoted.

```
$ echo "require('jquery')"
require('jquery')
```

Because the shell accepts single-quotes as part of double-quoted strings, the above works fine.

Sometimes, to avoid shell expansions, one needs everything to be in a single-quoted string.  In that case:

```
$ echo 'require('\''jquery'\'')'
require('jquery')
```

In the above, there are three single-quoted strings: `require(`, `jquery`, and  `)`.  In between those strings are single-quotes that are escaped so that the shell treats them as normal characters.

---

This answer assumes that the shell is bash, dash, ash, or other POSIX or bourne-derived shell.  For information on still other shells, see [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/312521/53604).

Comment: Depends on the shell, single quotes can be embedded in single-quoted strings in `fish` (`'foo\'bar'`) and `rc`/`es`/`akanga` (`'foo''bar'`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Interesting.  I updated my answer to note the portability issues.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes can not be nested, use double quotes around the pattern:

```
grep "require('jquery')" file.js
```

When you do:

```
grep 'require('jquery')' file.js
```

The shell is first breaking the pattern into 3 parts, based on the single quotes. First Literal `'require('`, then `jquery`, and then literal `')'`. So in effect the pattern is taken as `require(jquery)`, which is not matching anything expectedly.

**Example:**

```
$ cat foo.js 
var View = require('ampersand-view');
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
require('bootstrap-tooltip');
var extend = require('lodash/assign');

$ grep "require('jquery')" foo.js
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Answer (score 1):

In most shells, the `'` character is a quoting operator and the space character is used to separate arguments to a command. So your shell will parse that command as 3 arguments to pass to the `/bin/grep` command:

1. `grep`
2. `require(jquery)`
3. `index.js`

In `2` above, the `'require('jquery')'` has been taken as a *quoted* `require(` concatenated with an *unquoted* `jquery` concatenated with a *quoted* `)`.

You want `2` to be `require('jquery')`. Since `'`, like `(` and `)` is special character to the shell, you need to quote it in some way. The syntax depends on the shell. In Bourne-like shells, `fish` and `(t)csh`, you can use double-quote which they recognise as another quoting operator:

```
 grep "require('jquery')"
```

In `rc`-like shells (`rc`, `akanga`, `es`) where `'...'` is the only form of quoting, the syntax is:

```
 grep 'require(''jquery'')'
```

That double-`'` within `'...'` is the `rc` way to *escape* a `'` there.

For details on the special characters in the various Unix shells and how to *quote*/*escape* them, see [How to use a special character as a normal one?](/a/296147).

Answer (score 0):

Put the search pattern in double quotes.

```
grep "require('jquery')" index.js
```

Comment: @ikkachu, _Option 1_  works in the `fish` shell. The OP didn't specify which shell he was using.

Comment: I removed option 1 since I am not sure how many shells support it besides fish.